# Sliding windows in RxSwift

Tags: ios, rx-swift, sliding-window

Coming from the RxJava background, I can not come up with a standard approach to implement sliding windows in RxSwift. E.g. I have the following sequence of events:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, ...
```

Let's imagine event emission happens twice in a second. What I want to be able to do is to transform this sequence into a sequence of buffers, each buffer containing last three seconds of data. Plus, each buffer is to be emitted once in a second. So the result would look like that:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6], [3,4,5,6,7,8], [5,6,7,8,9,10], ...
```

What I would do in RxJava is I would use one of the overloads of the `buffer` method like so:

```
stream.buffer(3000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

Which leads exactly to the result I need to accomplish: sequence of buffers, each buffer is emitted once in a second and contains last three seconds of data.

I checked RxSwift docs far and wide and I did not find any overloads of `buffer` operator which would allow me to do that. Am I missing some non-obvious (for RxJava user, ofc) operator?

Comment: This question sent me down quite a rabbit hole. My current best answer resides in https://gist.github.com/dtartaglia/15416d95313255e12f009e3b1a9f79b8 It's a bit different than what I posted below. I changed it as I learned more about how the overlapping buffer operator works in .NET and Java.

Comment: This is probably the first time I see someone paying so much attention to the question that I posted. Thank you so much for all this work, I'll surely accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initially wrote the solution using a custom operator. I have since figured out how it can be done with the standard operators.

```
extension ObservableType {

    func buffer(timeSpan: RxTimeInterval, timeShift: RxTimeInterval, scheduler: SchedulerType) -> Observable<[E]> {
        let trigger = Observable<Int>.timer(timeSpan, period: timeShift, scheduler: scheduler)
            .takeUntil(self.takeLast(1))

        let buffer = self
            .scan([Date: E]()) { previous, current in
                var next = previous
                let now = scheduler.now
                next[now] = current
                return next.filter { $0.key > now.addingTimeInterval(-timeSpan) }
        }

        return trigger.withLatestFrom(buffer)
            .map { $0.sorted(by: { $0.key <= $1.key }).map { $0.value } }
    }
}
```

I'm leaving my original solution below for posterity:

---

Writing your own operator is the solution here.

```
extension ObservableType {

    func buffer(timeSpan: RxTimeInterval, timeShift: RxTimeInterval, scheduler: SchedulerType) -> Observable<[E]> {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            var buf: [Date: E] = [:]
            let lock = NSRecursiveLock()
            let elementDispoable = self.subscribe { event in
                lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
                switch event {
                case let .next(element):
                    buf[Date()] = element
                case .completed:
                    observer.onCompleted()
                case let .error(error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                }
            }
            let spanDisposable = scheduler.schedulePeriodic((), startAfter: timeSpan, period: timeShift, action: { state in
                lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
                let now = Date()
                buf = buf.filter { $0.key > now.addingTimeInterval(-timeSpan) }
                observer.onNext(buf.sorted(by: { $0.key <= $1.key }).map { $0.value })
            })
            return Disposables.create([spanDisposable, elementDispoable])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I've heard many times in RxJava community that if you think you need custom operator then 1. Think again. 2. Think one more time. 3. Review the available list of operators, if you don't find anything - get some rest then think again. The reason is that it's pretty easy to make the mistakes in the custom operator's implementation due to some intricacies. Apparently it's not the case in RxSwift because this is not the first time I see someone saying "Yeah, there is no operator in library, but here's a custom one". :)

Comment: Yea. The RxSwift library doesn't come with nearly as many operators. Another point for me at least is that I often can't figure out how to combine the existing operators to do exactly what I need, so I write the custom operator and then look at its implementation and see from that how use existing operators to do the same thing. Then I can just use my interface as a wrapper. An example is (https://gist.github.com/dtartaglia/1a70c4f7b8960d06bd7f1bfa81802cc3). If you look through the history, you can see that I originally implemented it myself.

Comment: I misunderstood how the operator was supposed to work. I have made an edit to fix both versions.